# can't resolve 'react' for mdl module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

Trying to build my first website with react, following along with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AboneIxeM8&t=599s

I am trying to install and use the [material lite module](https://github.com/tleunen/react-mdl), however when I start npm I get a failure to compile with the following message :

Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/user/node_modules/react-mdl/lib'

Can someone help me understand what this means and how to fix it ? I'm at a loss it seems above my skill level.

Comment: did you install react?

Comment: Do you have an existing `package-lock.json` file ??

Comment: Try running `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're following a tutorial there is probably some copy/ pasting involved. Hence, an already present `package-lock.json` file :)

I suggest doing the following:

- **Delete** `package-lock.json`
- Check if `node_modules/react` exists.
- If it doesn't, check if **`React`** is in your `package.json`. If you don't have it listed, add it. After that:
- Run `npm install` again
- Check if `node_modules/react` exists.
  [If it doesn't, something's messed up with your `npm` on your system. Try updating your NPM, or better yet, your [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) environment. -`npm` comes with it].

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save react-mdl then 
restart react server
```